# How to get the SQL server linked tables are connected to using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc

Is there a way to know which SQL Server the linked tables in MS Access database are pointing to using the ODBC connection?

I used the code below but I got the database name only and not the SQL server name.

```
Private Function checkconn()

Dim strConnect As String
Dim lngLocation As String

strConnect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_buh_summary").Connect
lngLocation = InStr(strConnect, ";DATABASE=")
If lngLocation <> 0 Then
GetDataPath = Mid(strConnect, lngLocation + 10)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: How many SQL Server instances do you have? Do they have same database name to cause confusion? Try printing out entire string with `Debug.Print strConnect` and check immediate window (CTRL + G).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used a FILE dsn to original link the tables?
(or a DSN less). I strong, but rather strong recommend you link always using a FILE dsn (not system or user). The reason is Access converts these links to DSN-less for you automatic. (and thus you don't need to setup a DSN on each computer).

Having noted  the above? You can grab the server and the database name with this:

```
Sub m34343()

  Dim strCon     As String

  strCon = CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_tblHotels3").Connect
  Debug.Print strCon

  Debug.Print Split(Split(strCon, "SERVER=")(1), ";")(0)
  Debug.Print Split(Split(strCon, "DATABASE=")(1), ";")(0)


End Sub
```

Output:

```
ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=ALBERTKALLAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;
     Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=test3

ALBERTKALLAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS
test3
```

So, I in above printed out the connection string, but then the next two lines grabs the server and the database name.